# SharePoint list total selected records not showing

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience

Am I the only who is facing that issue or its common.

[image: rePoint]

I am not able to see total selected records in list, while previously it was showing here how many records I selected.

Comment: I checked and showing the same behavior on my SharePoint sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was from Microsoft side, that was working fine after some time.
Not a issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also checked and showing the same behavior as you.

It is common.

[image]

Comment: but why microsoft disabled this feature.
Anyone have any idea?